# How to show data from database only related to the logged in user in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am creating a to-do list and now, for the user (not admin), the user can only see the task that only assigned to him, he knows it because under the assignee column is his name.

[image: Lala's task]

but now, not only he can see his own task (Lala's), but also the other's tasks

[image: Lala's and Haikal's tasks]

**JUST ASSUME THAT I HAVE CONNECTED TO THE DATABASE**

This is the login form (login.php),

```
<?php
 include('function.php');
?>

<form method="post" action="view.php">
 <?php echo display_error(); ?>

 <div class="input-group">
  <label> Username </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your username'" autocomplete="off">
 </div>

 <div class="input-group">
  <label> Password </label>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your password'" autocomplete="off">
 </div>

 <div class="input-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login_btn"> Login </button>
 </div>

 <p>
  Not yet a member? <a href="register.php" style="color:#1478F6;"> Sign up </a>
 </p>
</form>
```

this is the login function (function.php),

```
function isLoggedIn() {
 if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  return true;
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}

// call the login() function if register_btn is clicked
if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
 login();
}

// LOGIN USER
function login(){
 global $db, $username, $errors;

 // grap form values
 $username = e($_POST['username']);
 $password = e($_POST['password']);

 // make sure form is filled properly
 if (empty($username)) {
  array_push($errors, "Username is required");
 }

 if (empty($password)) {
  array_push($errors, "Password is required");
 }

 // attempt login if no errors on the form
 if (count($errors) == 0) {
  $password = md5($password);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
  $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // user found
   // check if the user is admin or user
   $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

   if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

    header('location: index.php');
   } else {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
    $_SESSION['success']  = "You are now logged in";

    header('location: view.php');
   }
  } else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
  }
 }
}
```

and this is the view.php to show the database (for now, showing all tasks for all users)

```
<?php
 include('function.php');

 if (!isLoggedIn()) {
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
  header('location: login.php');
 }
?>

<div class="container">
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th> Tasks </th>
    <th> Assignee </th>
    <th> Assigner </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <?php
    $results_per_page = 10;
    $tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks");
    $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($tasks);
    $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

    if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
      $page = 1;
    } else {
      $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $this_page_first_result = ($page - 1) * $results_per_page;

    $tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page);
    $i = 1; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tasks)) { ?>
     <tr>
      <td class="task"> <center> <?php echo $row['task']; ?> </center> </td>
      <td class="assignee"> <center> <?php echo $row['assignee']; ?> </center> </td>
      <td class="assigner"> <center> <?php echo $row['assigner']; ?> </center> </td>
     </tr>
    <?php $i++; } ?>

    <div class="pagination">
     <div class="pagination-container">
      <div class="pagination-hover-overlay"></div>

      <a href="#0" class="pagination-prev">
       <span class="icon-pagination icon-pagination-prev">
        <i class="icon material-icons">
         keyboard_arrow_left
        </i>
       </span>
      </a>

      <?php
       for ($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages ; $page++) {
        echo '<a class="pagination-page-number" href="view.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
       }
      ?>

      <a href="#0" class="pagination-next">
       <span class="icon-pagination icon-pagination-next">
        <i class="icon material-icons">
         keyboard_arrow_left
        </i>
       </span>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

So, the question is, how do I show the tasks from database that only the logged in user's username has the same name as the assignee, or something like that, you know what I mean. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Add a WHERE clause in to your 'tasks' query to identify rows belonging to the current user. Also, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks. You need to fix that ASAP.

Comment: need where with the logged in user id

Comment: **Warning!** You shouldn't use md5 for hashing passwords. As [the big red box in manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php): _"It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. Use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: Set Login User name in Session and check in task query where clause with assinee

Comment: 'SELECT d.data  FROM data d LEFT JOIN user u ON d.user_id = ' . $_SESSION['user']

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Answer (score 0):

I guess the value of field `Assignee` in table `tasks` is the username which is the unique value used for user authentication while log in. Also i guess `$_SESSION['user']` contains the username of logged in user.

So you have to add a 'where' clause in `MySql` query to dynamically fetch data of the logged in user only. Change the above queries to below.

```
$tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks where Assignee=".$_SESSION['username']);

$tasks = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tasks where Assignee=".$_SESSION['username']." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $results_per_page);
```